# WinDbg dump list private/shared working set. DLL module memory question

Tags: memory, module, windbg, dump, process-explorer

Do you guys know if there's any way in WinDbg to list the module memory usage like one would see in Process Explorer's DLL pane? I would like to know WS Private Shareable Shared Total. I have a full application dump I made by using Process Explorer and I suspect a memory leak from a DLL. I would like to compare two similar dumps to see what has changed in module memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`!address` should be able to give you that [information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff561519%28VS.85%29.aspx).

I would use [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) to figure this out.

Comment: Thanks. I've used !address but I was looking for something more streamlined. VMMap looks like a great tool but it doesn't work with dumps. I have a user experiencing a problem and I want to get their dump and compare it to mine. Specifically I want an analysis of the differences in memory usage.